# TSQL - WHILE LOOP

Tags: t-sql

```
WHILE @Suma < @ZalihaVP
begin
    Insert into @Promet (Kljuc, Kolicina, Datum, StarostPrometa)
    select top 1 m.acKey, anQTY, m.adDate, DATEDIFF(d, m.adDate, getdate())
    from tHE_Move m inner join tHE_MoveItem mi
    on m.acKey = mi.acKey
    where acReceiverStock = 'Y'
    and acReceiver = @Skladiste
    and acIdent = @Ident
    and m.acKey not in(select Kljuc from @Promet)
    order by adDate desc

    set @Suma = @Suma + (select SUM(kolicina) from @Promet)

    if @Suma > @ZalihaVP begin update @Promet set Kolicina = Kolicina - (@Suma - @ZalihaVP) where KLjuc = (select top 1 KLjuc from @Promet order by Datum) end
    if @Suma > @ZalihaVP begin set @Suma = @ZalihaVP end
end
```

This is my WHILE loop, I have problem here.
@ZalihaVP = 92
@Suma = 0

Records of @promet.kolicina are: 40, 50, 50

On third record, @Suma it's greather than @ZalihaVP 40 + 50 + 50 = 140 > @Suma
and third record it's not inserted, but I want them to insert.

How I can send @Suma < @Zaliha on the end after insert?

Comment: Send what? Send where? Come here after one year and if you will understand your own question I will buy you a bottle of beer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this row:

```
set @Suma = @Suma + (select SUM(kolicina) from @Promet)
```

There you set `@Suma` to itself plus all `kolicina` combined.

Maybe it should be:

```
set @Suma = select SUM(kolicina) from @Promet
```

Comment: Great...that's problem :)